# Yii grid-view buttons not working after changing the number of data items per page

Tags: php, ajax, gridview, yii, submit-button

I have an ongoing project with Yii 1.1 and I have some problems with custom grid-view buttons. The problem is this:
When I change the number of items displayed in the grid-view, an ajax call is made and the page displays the selected number of files, however a submit button (in the footer section of a column) defined as below will not work after ajax call:

```
array('class' => 'CDataColumn', 'type' => 'raw', 'header' => 'فایل مکالمه',
                    'value' => 'CdrController::getCdrSound($data)',
                    'footer' => CHtml::submitButton('دریافت همگی',     array('name' => 'action', 'action-data' => Yii::app()->createUrl("cdr/download"),   'class' => 'btn btn-small')) .
                         CHtml::submitButton('حذف صداها', array('name' => 'action', 'action-data' => Yii::app()->createUrl("cdr/deleteSound"), 'class' => 'btn btn-small btn-danger')),
                ),
```

I have to note that after a page refresh the submit button will work with new number of the displayed items and the html source of the view file before and after the ajax call is unchanged.